# Evaluate numerically an equation with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to ask something that provably is extremly easy but I didn't find how to do it... The point is that I want to define some function in python in a symbolic way using sympy in order to make its derivative and then use this expresion numerically.

Here an example is showed:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

z = Symbol('z')
function = z*exp(z**2)
deriv = diff(function, z)
x = np.arange(1, 3, 0.1) #interval of points
#How can I evaluate numerically this array "x" with the function deriv???
```

Do you know how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`lambdify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html#lambdify) with the `numpy` backend:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

z = Symbol('z')
function = z*exp(z**2)
deriv = diff(function, z)
x = np.arange(1, 3, 0.1) #interval of points
d = lambdify(z, deriv, "numpy")
d(x)
# array([  8.15484549e+00,   1.14689175e+01,   1.63762998e+01,
#          2.37373255e+01,   3.49286892e+01,   5.21825471e+01,
#          7.91672020e+01,   1.21994639e+02,   1.90992239e+02,
#          3.03860954e+02,   4.91383350e+02,   8.07886132e+02,
#          1.35069268e+03,   2.29681687e+03,   3.97320108e+03,
#          6.99317313e+03,   1.25255647e+04,   2.28335915e+04,
#          4.23706166e+04,   8.00431723e+04])
```